# CakePHP 4.0 Reusable Console (former Task)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I'm in the process of upgrading a CakePHP 2 system to CakePHP 4, I have a piece of code which opens tickets in a help desk system, with public functions to open, update, resolve etc

Previously I achieved this using Tasks (as it is triggered through the console), where is the best place to put it now that tasks are deprecated?

Also is it still possible to have models without tables using $useTable = false in version 4.x?

I've looked at Consoles inside Consoles but it seems messy, I haven't worked out how to call a specific function inside the target console.

Many thanks.

Comment: 1.reusable code move to Traits. 2. you can use controller without models.

Comment: Please try to avoid asking multiple questions that are unrelated. What was known as a `Model` class, is now a `Table` class, which is all about ORM, you can't just unconnect it from that. Whatever you have been solved by doing so, might be solvable in a different way now, but that is something for a separate question where you can provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Everything is a command

Everything is a command now, and they can be instantiated pretty much wherever you like, there is no automation for a subcommand process, how to build the interface is completely up to you now.

IMHO a command should not have many different public entry points, but ideally only do one thing, so you simply execute the command to do *x*, and don't call *x* and *y* and *z* on it to do many different things.

### Executing commands manually

Executing a command from a command is very simple, command classes have a helper method for that:

```php
$exitCode = $this->executeCommand(
    \App\Command\MySubcommand::class,
    ['--option', 'argument']
);
```

If the command needs to constructor arguments you can pass an instance of the command:

```php
$subCommand = new \App\Command\MySubcommand($constructorArguments);
$exitCode = $this->executeCommand($subCommand, ['--option', 'argument']);
```

This is perfectly fine to do, you can run your commands like that whenever you need them.

### Exposing commands to the CLI

To expose subcommands to the CLI with proper names, the most simple way would be to override the default name in your command class. Say the name of your parent command is `ParentCommand`, it could look something like this in your subcommand class:

```php
public static function defaultName(): string
{
    return 'parent sub';
}
```

You can then invoke that command via `bin/cake parent sub` and the parent command via `bin/cake parent` accordingly.

For more control over how commands are registered you can use the `console()` hook in your application class, where you have full control over what is being loaded and with what names. This for example would register only the `parent` command and the `parent sub` command:

```php
// in src/Application.php

public function console(\Cake\Console\CommandCollection $commands): \Cake\Console\CommandCollection
{
    // autoload app and core commands
    // $commands = parent::console($commands);

    // register commands with custom names
    $commands->add(
        'parent',
        \App\Command\ParentCommand::class
    );
    $commands->add(
        'parent sub',
        \App\Command\ParentSubCommand::class
    );

    return $commands;
}
```

### See also

- **[Cookbook > Console Commands > Command Objects > Calling other Commands](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/commands.html#calling-other-commands)**
- **[Cookbook > Console Commands > Command Objects > Changing the Default Command Name](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands/commands.html#changing-the-default-command-name)**
- **[Cookbook > Console Commands > Console Applications](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/console-commands.html#console-applications)**